# Hacer aparecer botones al hacer un hover

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Mi duda concretamente es la siguiente, si yo tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<ul class="skills-list">
    <li *ngFor="let skill of skills" class="skills">{{skill.nombreSkill}}</li>
</ul>
```

donde voy recorriendo un array y armando una lista, hay una forma para que yo al hacer hover sobre algun item se hagan dos botones? ya que quiero poner la posibilidad de editar o eliminar ese item
dejo dos imagenes para que sea un poco mas grafico
quiero que mi elemento se va normal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y que al pasar el mouse aparesca alguna opcion como esos tres puntos en la esquina derecha

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si se puede. Cada `li` debe contener un **div** que será el contenedor del icono de tres puntos para abrir un menú que tendrá las opciones en botón con funciones

Comment: claro pero mi duda esta mas enfocada en como hago para que esos 3 puntitos solo aparezcan cuando yo paso el mouse por encima solamente

Comment: Como te dije, debe estar en el `li` en el HTML o agregando desde una base de javascript e inicialmente debe estar invisible. Luego al hacer `hover` que se vea con `opacity`, `display block`, o `translate` o como sea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, supongamos que los tres puntos son un círculo.

```
//HTML
<ul class="skills-list">
<div class="container"> 
    <li class"dot" *ngFor="let skill of skills" class="skills" {{skill.nombreSkill}}</li>
</div>

</ul>
//CSS
.dot{
    background: lightblue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: none;
}

.container:hover{
   cursor:pointer;
   .dot{
     display:block;
   }
}
```

Puedes aplicar la misma lógica con cualquier elemento, pueden ser botones, texto, etc etc.
Básicamente lo que sucede es que todos los elementos tienen el círculo pero `display:none` hace que no sea visible, cuando agregamos `container:hover` le decimos que cuando el mouse este sobre el contenedor el elemento se haga visible.

Comment: Genial y a ese circulo en este caso que se genera, hay una forma de que al apretarlo haga alguna funcion? porque entiendo que se ve pero por lo que entiendo yo solo seria un circulo visible sin funcion

Comment: Claro, en este caso puedes crear un botón al cual le agregas una clase "myBtt", esta clase por defecto en css le colocas el display:none; Y en el contenedor en este caso tu li colocas la función de hover, que haga visible la clase "myBtt" con display:block. Espero haber sido claro, caso contrario responde el comentario y seré más específico si lo requieres.
Al agregar un botón ya puedes hacer click e interactuar con el. Aunque recuerda que con angular también podrías agregar el (click) en el div que construye el circulo :D

Comment: ahora juntando un poquito de cada uno lo pude hacer, pude hacer que me quedaran los dos botenes exactamente en el medio cuando hago el hover con position relative y absolute, mi nueva duda es, hay una forma que cuando yo hago el hover y se vean los dos botones la palabra que yo tenga de fondo se difumine?

Comment: Si, al texto que vas a agregar también debes agregarle una clase de css y asi como la clase cursor que esta dentro del container:hover debes agregarla y agregar las propiedades que harán al texto difuminado. Ese comportamiento se vera reflejado cuando haya un hover.